# Data Errors in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I'm working on a civic engagement app that will include a UITableView listing voter registration information for all 50 states and DC. I've compiled a [[String]] array as follows to serve as the data source:

```
[stateAbbv.,stateName,infoLink,onlineRegistrationLink]
```

EXAMPLE:

```
["MO","Missouri","https://www.sos.mo.gov/elections/govotemissouri/register","https://s1.sos.mo.gov/votemissouri/request"]
["SD","South Dakota","https://sdsos.gov/elections-voting/voting/register-to-vote/default.aspx","nil"]
```

To make the UITableView easier to populate, I've broken up the array into 4 separate Arrays in my viewDidLoad as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(voterInformation.count)
    for items in voterInformation
    {
        stateAbbreviations.append(items[0])
        stateNames.append(items[1])
        voteInfoLinks.append(items[2])
        onlineLink.append(items[3])
    }


    resultsTable.delegate=self
    resultsTable.dataSource=self
```

In my tableView cell method, I coded it so that if an online registration link does not exist, the "Online Registration" button is Hidden.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let newCell=resultsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stateRegistrationCell", for: indexPath) as! VoterRegistraionCell

    print(indexPath.row)

    newCell.stateName.text=stateNames[indexPath.row]
    //print(voterInformation[indexPath.row][3])
   if(voteInfoLinks[indexPath.row] == "No Voter Registration")
    {
        newCell.infoLink.setTitle("No Voter Registration", for: UIControlState.normal)
        newCell.onlineRegistration.isHidden=true
    }
    else
    {
        newCell.infoLink.tag=indexPath.row
        //print(voterInformation[indexPath.row][3])
        if(onlineLink[indexPath.row] != "nil")
        {newCell.onlineRegistration.tag=indexPath.row}
        else
        {
            newCell.onlineRegistration.isHidden=true
        }
    }

    return newCell
}
```

My question is, when I test this in the simulator, the links show up OK initially, but as I scroll down, some of the "Online Registration" links that were supposed to be there aren't there. And when I scroll back up, Online links that were there before are there no longer. (Alabama for instance). Any thoughts on why this data seems to be getting lost?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the cell is reused on scroll.

Implement the `prepareForReuse()` function in your Cell class, ans set your button to `isHidden=true`

Comment: So just to clarify, the onlineLink button would be hidden by default, then in the tableView method, I would check if the onlineLink exists and if it does, then change "isHidden" to false?

Comment: Exactly! So each presented cell will have the button hidden, except if you explicitly change that

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

set below this line `if(onlineLink[indexPath.row] != "nil")` this line `newCell.onlineRegistration.isHidden=false`